# Confused on normallity

Tags: acid-base, concentration

So normality is 'equivalents' over liters solution right? I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what an equivalent is. At first from one thing I read i thought it was just the H released from acids in the reactions but then something else started talking about ti with compounds without H, and in double/single displacement reactions. From part of what I read it sounds like a single would have 1 eq and 2 for double, but what found to read was pretty brief so I'm not fully sure. Can someone please explain these a bit better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normality = Equivalents of solute/liters of solution

Equivalents are determined by the number of electrons exchanged (or protons in water solutions, or yet other ions in different solvents). For example, if HCl is used to neutralize an alkali, then one mole of HCl will neutralize one mole of NaOH, *but* it takes **two** moles of HCl to neutralize one mole of Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> or **three** moles of Al(OH)<sub>3</sub>, because they have, respectively, two and three active OH<sup>-</sup> groups.

There are some pretty clear explanations in more detail at [Molarity, Molality and Normality](http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/chemistry/MolarityMolalityNormality.html) and at [Normality](http://chemistry.tutorvista.com/inorganic-chemistry/normality.html).

And then there's Mel Brooks *Abby Normal*...